# Post запрос в typescript

Tags: http, angular2, typescript, request

Нужна помощь с POST запросом. 
Делаю так:

```
let dataString = {
        username: 'test',
        password: 'test12345678'
    };

    let headers = new Headers({
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("EVRUHn28MQy54F4Mh9V0M1kwZqmGrj5X83rTSJHp" + ':' + "XVYbplQvNrK8zB6FyJdr1HXq6y8k4pdl2yeoBIFsjfZv6rzGtBLuefi5fu3g7j6FDHkxdxoIbHAjB8jGFJH8vvp3BDbZ1xQvl1SqPbrmU8GGfNaZWodIzxNsV98T7zCv")
    });

    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    let data = "username=" + dataString.username + "&password=" + encodeURIComponent(dataString.password) + "&grant_type=password&" +
        "client_secret=XVYbplQvNrK8zB6FyJdr1HXq6y8k4pdl2yeoBIFsjfZv6rzGtBLuefi5fu3g7j6FDHkxdxoIbHAjB8jGFJH8vvp3BDbZ1xQvl1SqPbrmU8GGfNaZWodIzxNsV98T7zCv&client_id=EVRUHn28MQy54F4Mh9V0M1kwZqmGrj5X83rTSJHp";

    let key = this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/o/token/', data, options).subscribe(result => result.json());
```

Ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

curl:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/o/token/ -d "grant_type=password&username=test&password=test12345678" -u "EVRUHn28MQy54F4Mh9V0M1kwZqmGrj5X83rTSJHp:XVYbplQvNrK8zB6FyJdr1HXq6y8k4pdl2yeoBIFsjfZv6rzGtBLuefi5fu3g7j6FDHkxdxoIbHAjB8jGFJH8vvp3BDbZ1xQvl1SqPbrmU8GGfNaZWodIzxNsV98T7zCv"
```

Comment: Это вопросы к серверу, почему он вам на preflight реквест не отвечает нужными разрешениями

Comment: а сервер на чем? это CORS ошибка, localhost:3002 должен быть в списке разрешенных доменов. Подробнее тут https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: @Umer, cервер на python

Comment: либо добавляйте разрешение на сервере, либо делайте проксирование запросов локально. для этого все есть из коробки. Если используете angular-cli то https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md

Comment: Сделал, установил CorsMiddleware и прописал в CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST свой  localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо установить CorsMiddleware и прописать в CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST свой localhost.

```
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
  'http://localhost:3002',
]
```